# How to make objects look in the direction of travel?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making my own copy of a game I saw but when I try to get the rockets to face the direction they are travelling in it just doesn't work consistently.

```
public class FriendlyRocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D self;
    private Vector2 mousePos;
    public Transform mouse;
    //public float timer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mouse = GameObject.Find("Mouse").transform;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        //mousePos.z += 10;
        //mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        transform.LookAt(mouse.transform);
        //transform.eulerAngles.z = 0;
        if (mousePos.x < 0) { transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, transform.eulerAngles.x + 90); }
        if (mousePos.x > 0) { transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, transform.eulerAngles.x + 270); }

        //self = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        //self.velocity = new Vector2(self.velocity.x, 10f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, mousePos, 10f * Time.deltaTime);
        /*if (timer < 0)
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if(timer>0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }*/
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would simply suspect that `transform.LookAt(mouse.transform);` isn't actually matching with `mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer the question without visual representation. But I believe the issue is associated with the fact that you set mousePos only on start but moving in mousePos direction each frame. So if mousePos cannot be changed than it is ok but is mousePos is changing during the time than you should also update the value of mousePos. And of course LookAt() should also be called each frame to update rotation if the direction is changed. I hope these ideas will help you.

Comment: but the target position is also not changed so this shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand the question but
you must update your `mousePos` in `void update()` for the object to follow the mouse:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, mousePos, 
    10f * Time.deltaTime);
    mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
transform.LookAt(target);
```